# What is the reason behind some of the biome anomalies in Africa?

Tags: meteorology, temperature, geography, ecology, altitude

For example :

1. The center of Africa lies in the Equatorial region and yet, does not have tropical rainforests all the way across.
2. The island of Madagascar has two different biomes

Since altitude and latitude doesn't seem to be the reason behind these anomalies, what other factors affect the biome of these places?

[image]

Comment: The hand-drawn circles aren't red. In stricter stacks that would earn a downvote. :)

Comment: The Monsoon/Trade Winds is/are the answer.

Comment: C'mon Eric....elaborate!